# How to extract a ZIP file that has a password using only PHP?

Tags: php, passwords, redhat, unzip

I have seen only one question on here but it does not answer my question. I am running a typical LAMP server that has the most up to date PHP 5 and MYSQL 5 with Redhat Linux.

I need to find a PHP only solution because my host does not allow me to use shell.

Here is my code that extracts ZIPs that are not passworded from vBulletin uploads to another directory:

```
if ($_GET['add'] == TRUE){
$zip = new ZipArchive;
 $res = $zip->open($SOURCE FOLDER);
 if ($res === TRUE) {
     $zip->extractTo('$DESTINATION FOLDER/');
     $zip->close();
     echo 'File has been added to the library successfuly';
     //Add a flag to that file to indicate it has already been added to the library.
     mysql_query("UPDATE attachment SET library = 1 WHERE filedataid='$fileid'");    
 } else {
     echo 'A uncompression or file error has occured';
 }}
```

There must be some way to do this using just PHP, surely! Thank you.

UPDATE: My host informs me that gzip is installed on the server but not 7-Zip. I am looking into shell access too.

Comment: When you say shell is not an option, do you mean that you cannot call system(), or do you mean that you cannot login to the server with a shell.

Comment: I cannot shell into the server, I am currently asking my host about system() access.

Comment: Ok, depending on whether your php is allowed to call system(), you could also check whether your host has unzip executable installed.  See edit in my answer.

Comment: Ok, apparently I should be able to call Gzip from PHP and I can actually get SSH access if I formally request it.

Comment: Good, but gzip does not handle .zip format, it handles .gz format. But if you get SSH access, you should be able to install 7zip for yourself. Or `unzip`, if not already installed.

Comment: OK I will see if that is possible, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have 7zip executable available to the script and call it to uncompress the file with the password via system().

```
$strCommandLine = "7z e fileToUnzip.7z -pTHEPASSWORD";
system($strCommandLine);
```

You can do something similar with `unzip`, if your host has that installed.  See http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_unzip.htm.

It supports -P with a password, so something like this:

```
$strCommandLine = "unzip fileToUnzip.7z -P THEPASSWORD";
system($strCommandLine);
```

Caveat: someone could see your password on that command line if they do a ps on the system and see your unzip command running.

Comment: Unfortunately 7-zip is not installed on my server. However my host informs me that Gzip is though.

Comment: OK here is the reply I got: "You wouldn't be able to install the software you need via SSH though, no. unzip is a basic tool that is available to Linux systems."

Comment: Great.  So if unzip is available, and if you can use system(), you're in business.

Comment: Ok I have tried this out but I get this in my error logs: [Wed Jan 02 21:57:35 2013] [error] [client 86.0.149.128] caution: filename not matched:  -P
[Wed Jan 02 21:57:35 2013] [error] [client 86.0.149.128] caution: filename not matched:  subw12.                                        Here is my code: $strCommandLine = "unzip test.zip -P subw12";
system($strCommandLine);

Comment: Looks like I put the password switch in the wrong place.  Try putting the password first `$strCommandLine = "unzip -P THEPASSWORD fileToUnzip.zip"`;

Comment: Ok so I have done: $strCommandLine = "unzip -P subw12 test.zip";
system($strCommandLine); ----- The script returns "Archive: test.zip" but there is nothing in the scripts directory. I have tried adding a destination but the error logs suggest that the script tries opening the directory as an archive.

Comment: Try adding `-d scripts` at the end, that tells it to extract to the scripts directory.  you may need to specify the full path the scripts directory.

Answer (score 6):

you can use this function setPassword ( string $password )
http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.setpassword.php

Comment: Note: Only available in (PHP 5 >= 5.6.0, PHP 7, PECL zip >= 1.12.4)